# Basic Auth with Tomcat behind IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, tomcat, basic-authentication

I am running a Tomcat behind an IIS on Windows Server 2008R2 machine. If I am connecting directly to Tomcat my Basic Auth (for API-Calls) are working. But as soon as I am connection via the IIS the Basic Auth Information gets lost and the request ist answered with an 403.

Thanks in advance,

Reto